# Error creating asset in moonbeam with zombienet

Tags: zombienet, moonbeam

I'm trying to create an asset but I always get this error:
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my config.toml:

```
[relaychain]
default_command = "./bin/polkadot"
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true
  ws_port = 9900
  extra_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true
  extra_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "charlie"
  validator = true
  extra_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "dave"
  validator = true


[[parachains]]
id = 1282
chain = "moonbeam-local"

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "alith"
  ws_port = 9910
  command = "./bin/moonbeam"
  args = ["-lparachain=debug"]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

I'm using polkadot v0.9.37 and moonbeam 0.30.0-483f51e8c25. I also tried using moonbeam-dev, moonbase-dev and moonbase-loca but I get the same error.

I noticed in Alith logs some warnings, can it be the problem?:

```
023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Moonbeam Parachain Collator    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.30.0-483f51e8c25    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by PureStake, 2019-2023    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Moonbeam Local Testnet    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: alith    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/lc/2st7lfb94fl0_1mp5jl2s8c80000gq/T/zombie-1d8ef25f5cffaeeacce6550020882db4_-46194-KYAdJOYVs0ME/alith/data/chains/moonbeam_local/db/full    
2023-04-25 09:33:15.255  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: moonbeam-2201 (moonbeam-0.tx2.au3)    
2023-04-25 09:33:16.268  INFO main moonbeam_cli::command: Parachain id: Id(1282)    
2023-04-25 09:33:16.268  INFO main moonbeam_cli::command: Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhNmfF6BURE35y65VanZ1nrUXyvdvPNF9keHhZHLtxJG    
2023-04-25 09:33:16.268  INFO main moonbeam_cli::command: Parachain genesis state: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045fe0ca1772dbeb70680d480be2ebaacae4e6c8945444e46f9561ae7b3cd8a8603170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400    
2023-04-25 09:33:16.268  INFO main moonbeam_cli::command: Is collating: yes    
2023-04-25 09:33:17.115  INFO main sc_service::client::client: []  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x45fe…8a86, header-hash: 0x39be…e12c)    
2023-04-25 09:33:17.916  INFO main sc_service::client::client: [Relaychain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xa2f1…fe39, header-hash: 0x70a7…4aa9)    
2023-04-25 09:33:17.920 DEBUG main parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Using dispute aware relay-chain selection algorithm
2023-04-25 09:33:17.920  INFO main grandpa: [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.657  INFO main babe: [Relaychain]  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.658  INFO main sub-libp2p: [Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWNWFU8YpAK9ekSHhCnkvpq82D2TABaVMJxfipVNRN8YSz    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.671  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Operating system: macos    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.671  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.671  INFO main sc_service::builder: [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #0    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.671  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: [Relaychain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9616    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:53798, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:53797, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU score: 810.05 MiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Memory score: 41.06 GiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 3.63 GiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.672  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 506.28 MiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.673  INFO tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Starting with an empty approval vote DB.
2023-04-25 09:33:18.673  WARN                 main sc_service::config: [] Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.673  INFO                 main sub-libp2p: []   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWCGmHA8TkwvxhCXhQgeragffknJL4qN1YQh4AwsE9EL4C    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] New session detected session_index=0
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks []
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Determined past/present/future authorities authority_count=4
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Issuing a connection request num=0
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] error=NotAValidator
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Validation num_peers=0 removed=0
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  Operating system: macos    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674  INFO                 main sc_service::builder: []  Highest known block at #0    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: [] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 0.0.0.0:53753    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.674  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [] Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=0.0.0.0:53752, allowed origins=["*"]    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [] Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=0.0.0.0:9910, allowed origins=["*"]    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  CPU score: 810.05 MiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  Memory score: 41.06 GiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  Disk score (seq. writes): 3.63 GiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: []  Disk score (rand. writes): 506.28 MiBs    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675 DEBUG                 main parachain: [] Restoring chain level monitor from last finalized block: 0 0x39be…e12c    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.675 DEBUG                 main parachain: [] Restored chain level monitor up to height 1    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.676  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour: [Relaychain] discovered: 12D3KooWCGmHA8TkwvxhCXhQgeragffknJL4qN1YQh4AwsE9EL4C /ip4/192.168.0.101/tcp/53751/ws    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.676  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour: [] discovered: 12D3KooWNWFU8YpAK9ekSHhCnkvpq82D2TABaVMJxfipVNRN8YSz /ip4/192.168.0.101/tcp/53796/ws    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.677  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  New epoch 0 launching at block 0x8bd3…5580 (block slot 280404932 >= start slot 280404932).    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.677  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  Next epoch starts at slot 280404942    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.678  WARN tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.679  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #1 (0x8bd3…5580)    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.679 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x70a724d6471f57dbaa991e000c05525d373e42e78392ba8563317b70e60d4aa9
2023-04-25 09:33:18.681 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x8bd3544e5eab484ba720d0ce8deb0e068824ea291b655a71a16f9a0a8a885580
2023-04-25 09:33:18.681 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=1 block_hash=0x8bd3544e5eab484ba720d0ce8deb0e068824ea291b655a71a16f9a0a8a885580 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:18.681 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x8bd3544e5eab484ba720d0ce8deb0e068824ea291b655a71a16f9a0a8a885580, 1)]
2023-04-25 09:33:18.681  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2 (0x44d0…0993)    
2023-04-25 09:33:18.681 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x8bd3544e5eab484ba720d0ce8deb0e068824ea291b655a71a16f9a0a8a885580
2023-04-25 09:33:18.682 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x44d06834116be872f902b4708db507c87f4efd04f3de2bb07e98c8cde9dd0993
2023-04-25 09:33:18.682 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=2 block_hash=0x44d06834116be872f902b4708db507c87f4efd04f3de2bb07e98c8cde9dd0993 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:18.682 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x44d06834116be872f902b4708db507c87f4efd04f3de2bb07e98c8cde9dd0993, 2)]
2023-04-25 09:33:21.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: Accepting new connection 1/100
2023-04-25 09:33:23.673  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #2 (0x44d0…0993), finalized #0 (0x70a7…4aa9), ⬇ 9.6kiB/s ⬆ 7.4kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:23.673 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339603 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:23.675  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:24.015  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #3 (0xa8e3…3f53)    
2023-04-25 09:33:24.017 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x44d06834116be872f902b4708db507c87f4efd04f3de2bb07e98c8cde9dd0993
2023-04-25 09:33:24.018 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0xa8e3ffd585325bef6b2995cb41792fd48dd998655b977e379de26e5a75c43f53
2023-04-25 09:33:24.018 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=3 block_hash=0xa8e3ffd585325bef6b2995cb41792fd48dd998655b977e379de26e5a75c43f53 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:24.018 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xa8e3ffd585325bef6b2995cb41792fd48dd998655b977e379de26e5a75c43f53, 3)]
2023-04-25 09:33:26.641 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x8bd3544e5eab484ba720d0ce8deb0e068824ea291b655a71a16f9a0a8a885580 block_number=1
2023-04-25 09:33:28.518  INFO tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: Accepting new connection 1/100
2023-04-25 09:33:28.677 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339608 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:28.677  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #3 (0xa8e3…3f53), finalized #1 (0x8bd3…5580), ⬇ 5.4kiB/s ⬆ 3.3kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:28.677  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 79 B/s ⬆ 79 B/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:30.031  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #4 (0x2eef…5a1b)    
2023-04-25 09:33:30.031 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xa8e3ffd585325bef6b2995cb41792fd48dd998655b977e379de26e5a75c43f53
2023-04-25 09:33:30.033  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #4 (0x98c0…917f)    
2023-04-25 09:33:30.036 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-distribution: [Relaychain] Dispute coordinator slow? We are still waiting for data on next active leaves update.
2023-04-25 09:33:30.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x2eef570f223d1a8bede53eb9b583c13bbd5bdf790c125168b707e9f9a5a65a1b
2023-04-25 09:33:30.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=4 block_hash=0x2eef570f223d1a8bede53eb9b583c13bbd5bdf790c125168b707e9f9a5a65a1b num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:30.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x2eef570f223d1a8bede53eb9b583c13bbd5bdf790c125168b707e9f9a5a65a1b, 4)]
2023-04-25 09:33:30.038 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x98c0832e090527293e8642e22d0e4ee714e8b4e5426efb7f0b67a1eddc19917f
2023-04-25 09:33:30.038 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=4 block_hash=0x98c0832e090527293e8642e22d0e4ee714e8b4e5426efb7f0b67a1eddc19917f num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:30.038 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x98c0832e090527293e8642e22d0e4ee714e8b4e5426efb7f0b67a1eddc19917f, 4)]
2023-04-25 09:33:33.679 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339613 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:33.680  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #4 (0x2eef…5a1b), finalized #1 (0x8bd3…5580), ⬇ 3.6kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:33.680  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-25 09:33:34.676 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x44d06834116be872f902b4708db507c87f4efd04f3de2bb07e98c8cde9dd0993 block_number=2
2023-04-25 09:33:36.030  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #5 (0x9d1d…f3b6)    
2023-04-25 09:33:36.030 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x2eef570f223d1a8bede53eb9b583c13bbd5bdf790c125168b707e9f9a5a65a1b
2023-04-25 09:33:36.033 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x9d1d170e51affb122413baae533d39ae0b51d57fe6ca1cb398ad1de908fdf3b6
2023-04-25 09:33:36.033 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=5 block_hash=0x9d1d170e51affb122413baae533d39ae0b51d57fe6ca1cb398ad1de908fdf3b6 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:36.033 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x9d1d170e51affb122413baae533d39ae0b51d57fe6ca1cb398ad1de908fdf3b6, 5)]
2023-04-25 09:33:36.033  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #5 (0xde54…3a73)    
2023-04-25 09:33:36.034 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0xde540b7ad56c1249c2422510afebcedb3d8c5eccf8bfc8b3161201ee5fe43a73
2023-04-25 09:33:36.034 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=5 block_hash=0xde540b7ad56c1249c2422510afebcedb3d8c5eccf8bfc8b3161201ee5fe43a73 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:36.034 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xde540b7ad56c1249c2422510afebcedb3d8c5eccf8bfc8b3161201ee5fe43a73, 5)]
2023-04-25 09:33:38.686 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339618 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:38.686  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #5 (0x9d1d…f3b6), finalized #2 (0x44d0…0993), ⬇ 3.2kiB/s ⬆ 2.1kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:38.686  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:38.689 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xa8e3ffd585325bef6b2995cb41792fd48dd998655b977e379de26e5a75c43f53 block_number=3
2023-04-25 09:33:42.028  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #6 (0xbd15…5084)    
2023-04-25 09:33:42.028 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x9d1d170e51affb122413baae533d39ae0b51d57fe6ca1cb398ad1de908fdf3b6
2023-04-25 09:33:42.030 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0xbd15c24dcff6b676af087227743eea46f4850a64fa2070e7c8e9fb31de3b5084
2023-04-25 09:33:42.030 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=6 block_hash=0xbd15c24dcff6b676af087227743eea46f4850a64fa2070e7c8e9fb31de3b5084 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:42.030 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xbd15c24dcff6b676af087227743eea46f4850a64fa2070e7c8e9fb31de3b5084, 6)]
2023-04-25 09:33:43.690 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339623 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:43.691  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #6 (0xbd15…5084), finalized #3 (0xa8e3…3f53), ⬇ 2.9kiB/s ⬆ 2.7kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:43.691  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-25 09:33:46.717 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x98c0832e090527293e8642e22d0e4ee714e8b4e5426efb7f0b67a1eddc19917f
2023-04-25 09:33:46.717 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x2eef570f223d1a8bede53eb9b583c13bbd5bdf790c125168b707e9f9a5a65a1b block_number=4
2023-04-25 09:33:48.032  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #7 (0x94a9…ac6a)    
2023-04-25 09:33:48.034 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xbd15c24dcff6b676af087227743eea46f4850a64fa2070e7c8e9fb31de3b5084
2023-04-25 09:33:48.036 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x94a9187462a341ba057b526c15605ac3a83e0245df20bf80bb5c5872157fac6a
2023-04-25 09:33:48.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=7 block_hash=0x94a9187462a341ba057b526c15605ac3a83e0245df20bf80bb5c5872157fac6a num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:48.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x94a9187462a341ba057b526c15605ac3a83e0245df20bf80bb5c5872157fac6a, 7)]
2023-04-25 09:33:48.692 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339628 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:48.695  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #7 (0x94a9…ac6a), finalized #4 (0x2eef…5a1b), ⬇ 2.4kiB/s ⬆ 2.1kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:48.695  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:50.736 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x9d1d170e51affb122413baae533d39ae0b51d57fe6ca1cb398ad1de908fdf3b6 block_number=5
2023-04-25 09:33:50.737 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xde540b7ad56c1249c2422510afebcedb3d8c5eccf8bfc8b3161201ee5fe43a73
2023-04-25 09:33:53.695 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339633 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:53.696  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #7 (0x94a9…ac6a), finalized #5 (0x9d1d…f3b6), ⬇ 3.6kiB/s ⬆ 2.2kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:53.696  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-25 09:33:54.036  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #8 (0xd158…5e05)    
2023-04-25 09:33:54.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x94a9187462a341ba057b526c15605ac3a83e0245df20bf80bb5c5872157fac6a
2023-04-25 09:33:54.040 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0xd1589f3741d5fceb8af08d98da8f565ad6c19403259f6e1b4f2e4b64892c5e05
2023-04-25 09:33:54.040 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=8 block_hash=0xd1589f3741d5fceb8af08d98da8f565ad6c19403259f6e1b4f2e4b64892c5e05 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:33:54.040 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xd1589f3741d5fceb8af08d98da8f565ad6c19403259f6e1b4f2e4b64892c5e05, 8)]
2023-04-25 09:33:58.700 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339638 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:33:58.701  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #8 (0xd158…5e05), finalized #5 (0x9d1d…f3b6), ⬇ 1.6kiB/s ⬆ 1.1kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:33:58.701  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-25 09:33:58.768 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xbd15c24dcff6b676af087227743eea46f4850a64fa2070e7c8e9fb31de3b5084 block_number=6
2023-04-25 09:34:00.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #9 (0x3c83…7789)    
2023-04-25 09:34:00.034 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0xd1589f3741d5fceb8af08d98da8f565ad6c19403259f6e1b4f2e4b64892c5e05
2023-04-25 09:34:00.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x3c8333a7a58ed6eb576016f741aa4442a96944a8272b1e55630d8b3bbc787789
2023-04-25 09:34:00.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=9 block_hash=0x3c8333a7a58ed6eb576016f741aa4442a96944a8272b1e55630d8b3bbc787789 num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:34:00.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x3c8333a7a58ed6eb576016f741aa4442a96944a8272b1e55630d8b3bbc787789, 9)]
2023-04-25 09:34:02.780 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x94a9187462a341ba057b526c15605ac3a83e0245df20bf80bb5c5872157fac6a block_number=7
2023-04-25 09:34:03.701 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339643 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:34:03.702  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #9 (0x3c83…7789), finalized #7 (0x94a9…ac6a), ⬇ 3.4kiB/s ⬆ 2.9kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:34:03.702  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 49 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s    
2023-04-25 09:34:06.032  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #10 (0x0042…469d)    
2023-04-25 09:34:06.033 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x3c8333a7a58ed6eb576016f741aa4442a96944a8272b1e55630d8b3bbc787789
2023-04-25 09:34:06.036  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #10 (0xa071…5e6a)    
2023-04-25 09:34:06.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0x0042fb3548d9d61f4362deb38b02fda28bb58df0653c63cbbcf6a0be2987469d
2023-04-25 09:34:06.037 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=10 block_hash=0x0042fb3548d9d61f4362deb38b02fda28bb58df0653c63cbbcf6a0be2987469d num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:34:06.038 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0x0042fb3548d9d61f4362deb38b02fda28bb58df0653c63cbbcf6a0be2987469d, 10)]
2023-04-25 09:34:06.042 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Insta-approving all candidates block_hash=0xa0711804f52dbac01f0e5ef0d3254b217097348993bffc0329f819c150785e6a
2023-04-25 09:34:06.042 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Imported new block. block_number=10 block_hash=0xa0711804f52dbac01f0e5ef0d3254b217097348993bffc0329f819c150785e6a num_candidates=0
2023-04-25 09:34:06.042 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Got new blocks [(0xa0711804f52dbac01f0e5ef0d3254b217097348993bffc0329f819c150785e6a, 10)]
2023-04-25 09:34:08.705 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1682339648 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-04-25 09:34:08.707  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: []  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x39be…e12c), finalized #0 (0x39be…e12c), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-25 09:34:08.707  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #10 (0x0042…469d), finalized #7 (0x94a9…ac6a), ⬇ 2.2kiB/s ⬆ 1.7kiB/s    
2023-04-25 09:34:10.817 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xd1589f3741d5fceb8af08d98da8f565ad6c19403259f6e1b4f2e4b64892c5e05 block_number=8
2023-04-25 09:34:12.031  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  New epoch 1 launching at block 0x4a80…73b5 (block slot 280404942 >= start slot 280404942).    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.031  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  Next epoch starts at slot 280404952    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  New epoch 1 launching at block 0x2cbe…cb10 (block slot 280404942 >= start slot 280404942).    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe: [Relaychain]  Next epoch starts at slot 280404952    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.034  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #11 (0x4a80…73b5)    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.035 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x0042fb3548d9d61f4362deb38b02fda28bb58df0653c63cbbcf6a0be2987469d
2023-04-25 09:34:12.036  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #11 (0x2cbe…cb10)    
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] New session detected session_index=1
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-distribution: [Relaychain] Dispute coordinator slow? We are still waiting for data on next active leaves update.
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039  INFO tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Advanced session window for approvals update=Advanced { prev_window_start: 0, prev_window_end: 0, new_window_start: 0, new_window_end: 1 }
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Determined past/present/future authorities authority_count=4
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] Issuing a connection request num=0
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: [Relaychain] error=NotAValidator
2023-04-25 09:34:12.039 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: [Relaychain] New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Validation num_peers=0 removed=0
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, I don't think this error is related to zombienet but I will try to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Zombienet issue.

This is a `CallFilter` issue.

It may be that your moon-xxx chain is running with a `NormalFilter`:

```rust
/// Normal Call Filter
/// **We dont allow to create nor mint assets**, this for now is disabled
/// We only allow transfers. For now creation of assets will go through
/// asset-manager, while minting/burning only happens through xcm messages
/// This can change in the future
pub struct NormalFilter;
impl Contains<RuntimeCall> for NormalFilter {
```

- https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/0545adc8c95551b2edfd263d7e1d77bbeeea1855/runtime/moonriver/src/lib.rs#L1000-L1005

Comment: I see, thank you. I was able to create assets with assetManager pallet